# Object creation pattern for component classes

Tags: c#, inheritance, unity3d

I've been grappling with Unity's architecture for the last few days, trying to work around the fact that you can't use constructors for your `MonoBehaviour`s (and by extension, you can't easily configure components before `Awake` if you create them programmatically). I've got a pattern now that I'm fairly happy with, but before I get to the code, here are a few things I'm trying to solve with it:

- Keep self-initialisation code in `Awake`, because that's where Unity developers would expect it, and it also ensures that the component is usable as soon is its game object is active. (As opposed to putting initialisation code in `Start` for example, which wouldn't happen until the next frame, or making users have to call some custom `Initialize` method which they might forget.)
- Make certain component fields configurable in all three forms of component creation: a) in the Inspector, b) when adding a component to a game object, c) when creating a prefab which contains the component somewhere in its hierarchy. In any case, this configuration needs to happen before the self-initialisation which will likely depend on these values.
- Otherwise, hide those fields from the outside, so that other code can't mess with the values after self-initialisation is complete (unless there's an explicitly exposed setter, of course).
- Statically control possible sets of initialisation parameters (like the signatures of available constructors would do).

The main concession I had to make to achieve those goals is that my object creation pattern can only be used when adding components to inactive game objects (because otherwise, `Awake` gets run before I can do anything). In practice, that's a restriction I can easily work with in my project.

Anyway, here is a complete component implementing the pattern:

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;

namespace MyProject
{
    public class ContentButton : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField] private string contentPath;
        [SerializeField] private bool isActive;

        private bool initialized = false;

        public static ContentButton AddTo(
            GameObject gameObject,
            string contentPath,
            bool isActive)
        {
            if (gameObject.activeInHierarchy)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Cannot add component to active game object.", nameof(gameObject));
            }

            var contentButton = gameObject.AddComponent<ContentButton>();
            contentButton.Initialize(contentPath, isActive);

            return contentButton;
        }

        public void Initialize(string contentPath, bool isActive)
        {
            if (initialized)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot initialize component after Awake().");
            }

            this.contentPath = contentPath;
            this.isActive = isActive;
        }

        private void Awake()
        {
            /* Perform any initialization logic here, like reading the file
               at contentPath. */

            initialized = true;
        }

        /* other MonoBehaviour callbacks omitted */
    }
}
```

The idea is that you use `MyComponent.AddTo(gameObject, ...)` instead of `gameObject.AddComponent<MyComponent>()` to create single components and that prefabs can be configured by instantiating them with an inactive parent and then calling `Initialize` on the relevant components before switching the lights on.

So first of all, is there anything wrong with this pattern on its own? Are there easier or more idiomatic ways to achieve the above goals?

The thing is that this is a lot of boilerplate code which I'd need to repeat on every single component in my project, which is just really prone to messing things up. I'd like to have a (potentially abstract) `BaseComponent` class which inherits from `MonoBehaviour` and from which all of my actual components inherit. That base class would then implement and/or enforce this pattern for all of its derived classes. A lot of the pattern should be the same on all derived classes (e.g. the entire body of `AddTo`, the exception in `Initialize` and the `initialize = true;` at the end of `Awake`). The body of `Initialize` is also essentially completely determined by the list of fields I want to expose, because this method should never do more than setting up the fields in the Inspector.

I'd normally enforce things like this with the template method pattern, but I'm not sure how to apply it in this case, where the signatures of `AddTo` and `Initialize` depend on the derived class. Is there any clean solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: I've only played very briefly with Unity, so cannot comment on accepted practice, or whether my comments are actually viable.

It seems to me that the only reason for your `AddTo()` method is to enforce the initialization parameter sets. However, this does not actually enforce construction in this way, because you are always free to just write `gameObject.AddComponent<ContentButton>();`

Could you not just keep `AddComponent` calls vanilla, and just initialize immediately afterward? By returning the instance from your `Init()` method you could easily chain calls to something like this:

```
var contentButton = gameObject.AddComponent<ContentButton>().Init(blah, blah);
```

You do lose your runtime debug check for active objects doing this, but this could be moved into a base implementation of `Init()` along with the awake check:

```
public class BehaviourBase : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool isAwake;

    [Conditional("DEBUG")]   // Or whatever Unity equivalent is
    protected void Init()
    {
        if (this.isAwake)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot initialize component after Awake().");

        if (this.gameObject != null && this.gameObject.activeInHierarchy)
            throw new ArgumentException("Cannot add component to active game object.", nameof(this.gameObject));
    }

    [Conditional("DEBUG")]
    protected void Awake()
    {
        this.isAwake = true;
    }  
}
```

Which would make your `ContentButton` implementation something like:

```
public class ContentButton : BehaviourBase
{
    [SerializeField] private string contentPath;
    [SerializeField] private bool isActive;

    public ContentButton Init(string contentPath, bool isActive)
    {
        base.Init();

        // standard constructor like stuff
        this.contentPath = contentPath;
        this.isActive = isActive;

        return this;
    }

    private void Awake()
    {
        base.Awake();

        /* Perform any initialization logic here, like reading the file
           at contentPath. */
    }

    /* other MonoBehaviour callbacks omitted */
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I like that `Conditional` attribute, I'll see which compilation symbols Unity defines. One issue with separating the calls like this is that `Init` can't actually determine whether the component was added to an active object (the moment you activate the object, `Awake` gets called, so the first check would fail already; you couldn't ever get to the second check and have it fail). I realise that I can't actually prevent use of a plain `AddComponent<>()` call, but I guess the idea was to include `AddTo` to suggest the correct usage to the programmer. [tbc]

Comment: I mean in principle there's nothing wrong with allowing the programmer to add an uninitialised component to an active game object... they'd just get the default values for the fields. But I was hoping the structure of `AddTo` and `Initialize` would make it clear that *if* they want to configure the component, they'll have to use `AddTo` or do something equivalent themselves.

Comment: Couldn't you just swap the checks around to check for an active gameObject first? I understand what you were trying to achieve with the `AddTo`, but it just feels fairly clunky to me just to try and prevent something that, like you say, is perfectly legal. But, lIke I said, I'm no Unity guy.

Comment: That would lead to misleading exceptions when you add the component correctly but try to configure it after `Awake`. The real issue is that at the point of `Init` you can no longer tell how the component was added. What I'm considering now though is to add an extension method `AddConfigurableComponent<T>` to `GameObject` as an alternative to `AddComponent` which includes the check. (And then chain the calls with `Init` like you suggested.) This gives the programmer the option to choose whether or not to include the check when creating the component.